# Unity3D Mecanim Character stopping before turning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logic, game-physics

so for the past few days I've been working on a character controller in Unity3D using mecanim. It's not based off of my own code, but off of a tutorial I found online, of course that tutorial was meant for Unity 4, so I am running in to small problems here and there, but nothing I couldn't fix up until now.

So the basic problem is that my character seems to (without reason) stop all his momentum and slowly turns around when I try to make a hard 180 degrees turn, afterwards he continues to run like normal again, but I don't see why he would suddenly stop turning.

Here is my character logic script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class characterLogic : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private Animator animator;
[SerializeField]
private FollowCamera gamecam;
[SerializeField]
private float directionSpeed = 1.5f;
[SerializeField]
private float directionDampTime = 0.25f;
[SerializeField]
private float rotationDegreePerSecond = 120f;
[SerializeField]
private float speedDampTime = 0.05f;

private float speed = 0.0f;
private float direction = 0.0f;
private float charAngle = 0f;
private float horizontal = 0.0f;
private float vertical = 0.0f;
private AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo;
private AnimatorTransitionInfo transInfo;

private int m_LocomotionId = 0;
private int m_LocomotionPivotLId = 0;
private int m_LocomotionPivotRId = 0;
private int m_LocomotionPivotLTransId = 0;  
private int m_LocomotionPivotRTransId = 0;  

public Animator Animator
{
    get
    {
        return this.animator;
    }
}

public float Speed
{
    get
    {
        return this.speed;
    }
}

public float LocomotionThreshold { get { return 0.2f; } }


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    if(animator.layerCount >= 2)
    {
        animator.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
    }   

    m_LocomotionId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Locomotion");
    m_LocomotionPivotLId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.LocomotionPivotL");
    m_LocomotionPivotRId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.LocomotionPivotR");
    m_LocomotionPivotLTransId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Locomotion -> Base Layer.LocomotionPivotL");
    m_LocomotionPivotRTransId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Locomotion -> Base Layer.LocomotionPivotR");

}

public void keysToWorldSpace (Transform root, Transform camera, ref float directionOut, ref float speedOut, ref float angleOut, bool isPivoting){

    Vector3 rootDirection = root.forward;

    Vector3 keyDirection = new Vector3 (horizontal, 0, vertical);

    speedOut = keyDirection.sqrMagnitude;

    //get camera rotation
    Vector3 cameraDirection = camera.forward;
    cameraDirection.y = 0.0f;
    Quaternion referentialShift = Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3.forward, cameraDirection);

    //convert key input to world space coordinates
    Vector3 moveDirection = referentialShift * keyDirection;
    Vector3 axisSign = Vector3.Cross (moveDirection, rootDirection);

    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), moveDirection, Color.green);
    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), axisSign, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), rootDirection, Color.magenta);
    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), keyDirection, Color.blue);

    float angleRootToMove = Vector3.Angle(rootDirection, moveDirection) * (axisSign.y >= 0 ? -1f : 1f);
    if (!isPivoting)
    {
        angleOut = angleRootToMove;
    }

    angleRootToMove /= 180f;

    directionOut = angleRootToMove * directionSpeed;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (animator) {

        stateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
        transInfo = animator.GetAnimatorTransitionInfo(0);

        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        charAngle = 0f;
        direction = 0f;

        keysToWorldSpace (this.transform, gamecam.transform, ref direction, ref speed, ref charAngle, isInPivot());

        animator.SetFloat ("Speed", speed);
        animator.SetFloat ("Direction", direction, directionDampTime, Time.deltaTime);

        if(speed > LocomotionThreshold){

            if(!isInPivot()){

                Animator.SetFloat("Angle", charAngle);

            }

        }
        if(speed < LocomotionThreshold && Mathf.Abs(horizontal) < 0.05f){

            animator.SetFloat("Direction", 0f);
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", speed, speedDampTime, Time.deltaTime);

        }

        Debug.Log(Speed);
        Debug.Log(charAngle);

    }

}

void FixedUpdate() {

    if (IsInLocomotion () && ((direction >= 0 && horizontal >= 0) || (direction < 0 && horizontal < 0))) {

        Vector3 rotationAmount = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(0f, rotationDegreePerSecond * (horizontal < 0f ? -1f : 1f), 0f), Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
        Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationAmount * Time.deltaTime);
        this.transform.rotation = (this.transform.rotation * deltaRotation);

    }

}

public bool isInPivot(){

    return stateInfo.fullPathHash == m_LocomotionPivotLId || 
            stateInfo.fullPathHash == m_LocomotionPivotRId || 
            transInfo.nameHash == m_LocomotionPivotLTransId || 
            transInfo.nameHash == m_LocomotionPivotRTransId;

}

public bool IsInLocomotion(){

    return stateInfo.fullPathHash == m_LocomotionId;

}
```

}

I believe it either has to do something with this script or with the transitions within mecanim. I also ported the finished product (found here: https://github.com/jm991/UnityThirdPersonTutorial ) of the tutorial over to Unity 5 and didn't experience the same problem there, I am not entirely sure what the difference is which gives me this problem, but if any of you know or find out, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself already!

Here is the new code in case anyone is interested in the future:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class characterLogic : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private Animator animator;
[SerializeField]
private FollowCamera gamecam;
[SerializeField]
private float directionSpeed = 1.5f;
[SerializeField]
private float directionDampTime = 0.25f;
[SerializeField]
private float rotationDegreePerSecond = 120f;
[SerializeField]
private float speedDampTime = 0.05f;
[SerializeField]
private float fovDampTime = 3f;

private float horizontal = 0.0f;
private float vertical = 0.0f;
private float speed = 0.0f;
private float direction = 0.0f;
private float charAngle = 0f;
private const float SPRINT_SPEED = 2.0f;
private const float SPRINT_FOV = 75.0f;
private const float NORMAL_FOV = 60.0f;
private const float WALK_SPEED = 0.1f;
private AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo;
private AnimatorTransitionInfo transInfo;

private int m_LocomotionId = 0;
private int m_LocomotionPivotLId = 0;
private int m_LocomotionPivotRId = 0;
private int m_LocomotionPivotLTransId = 0;  
private int m_LocomotionPivotRTransId = 0;  

public Animator Animator
{
    get
    {
        return this.animator;
    }
}

public float Speed
{
    get
    {
        return this.speed;
    }
}

public float LocomotionThreshold { get { return 0.2f; } }


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    if(animator.layerCount >= 2)
    {
        animator.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
    }   

    m_LocomotionId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Locomotion");
    m_LocomotionPivotLId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.LocomotionPivotL");
    m_LocomotionPivotRId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.LocomotionPivotR");
    m_LocomotionPivotLTransId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Locomotion -> Base Layer.LocomotionPivotL");
    m_LocomotionPivotRTransId = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.Locomotion -> Base Layer.LocomotionPivotR");

}

public void keysToWorldSpace (Transform root, Transform camera, ref float directionOut, ref float speedOut, ref float angleOut, bool isPivoting){

    Vector3 rootDirection = root.forward;

    Vector3 keyDirection = new Vector3 (horizontal, 0, vertical);

    speedOut = keyDirection.sqrMagnitude;

    //get camera rotation
    Vector3 cameraDirection = camera.forward;
    cameraDirection.y = 0.0f;
    Quaternion referentialShift = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, Vector3.Normalize(cameraDirection));

    //convert key input to world space coordinates
    Vector3 moveDirection = referentialShift * keyDirection;
    Vector3 axisSign = Vector3.Cross (moveDirection, rootDirection);

    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), moveDirection, Color.green);
    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), axisSign, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), rootDirection, Color.magenta);
    Debug.DrawRay (new Vector3(root.position.x, root.position.y + 2f, root.position.z), keyDirection, Color.blue);

    float angleRootToMove = Vector3.Angle(rootDirection, moveDirection) * (axisSign.y >= 0 ? -1f : 1f);
    if (!isPivoting)
    {
        angleOut = angleRootToMove;
    }

    angleRootToMove /= 180f;

    directionOut = angleRootToMove * directionSpeed;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (animator) {

        stateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
        transInfo = animator.GetAnimatorTransitionInfo(0);

        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        charAngle = 0f;
        direction = 0f;
        float charSpeed = 0f;

        keysToWorldSpace (this.transform, gamecam.transform, ref direction, ref charSpeed, ref charAngle, isInPivot());

        if (Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
        {
            speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, SPRINT_SPEED, Time.deltaTime);
            gamecam.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(gamecam.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, SPRINT_FOV, fovDampTime * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            speed = charSpeed;
            gamecam.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(gamecam.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, NORMAL_FOV, fovDampTime * Time.deltaTime);      
        }

        if (Input.GetButton("Walk"))
        {
            speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, WALK_SPEED, Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            speed = charSpeed;      
        }

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", speed, speedDampTime, Time.deltaTime);
        animator.SetFloat("Direction", direction, directionDampTime, Time.deltaTime);

        if(speed > LocomotionThreshold){

            if(!isInPivot()){

                Animator.SetFloat("Angle", charAngle);

            }

        }
        if(speed < LocomotionThreshold && Mathf.Abs(horizontal) < 0.05f){

            animator.SetFloat("Direction", 0f);
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", speed, speedDampTime, Time.deltaTime);

        }

        Debug.Log(Speed);
        Debug.Log(charAngle);

    }

}

void FixedUpdate() {

    if (IsInLocomotion () && ((direction >= 0 && horizontal >= 0) || (direction < 0 && horizontal < 0))) {

        Vector3 rotationAmount = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(0f, rotationDegreePerSecond * (horizontal < 0f ? -1f : 1f), 0f), Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
        Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationAmount * Time.deltaTime);
        this.transform.rotation = (this.transform.rotation * deltaRotation);

    }

}

public bool isInPivot(){

    return stateInfo.fullPathHash == m_LocomotionPivotLId || 
            stateInfo.fullPathHash == m_LocomotionPivotRId || 
            transInfo.nameHash == m_LocomotionPivotLTransId || 
            transInfo.nameHash == m_LocomotionPivotRTransId;

}

public bool IsInLocomotion(){

    return stateInfo.fullPathHash == m_LocomotionId;

}
```

}

It turned out that the guy who made the original code was using a dampTime on his speed due to which he wouldn't instantly stand still if he'd let go off a button. It's something he hadn't explained in his tutorial yet, so I must have missed it. Anyways I hope this might help anyone in the future with a similar problem.